# Incremental Checkpoint Data Size ( Flink)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-checkpoint

we are using Flink and we have enabled the incremental checkpointing by setting state.backend.incremental=true. We are using rocksdb as state backend. With incremental checkpointing, we expect "Checkpointed Data Size" to be smaller than "Full Checkpoint Data Size" on the Flink UI but it's the same. As you can see the screenshot. [image: ScreenShot]

Please let me know someone has an idea about it.

"Checkpointed Data Size" should be smaller than "Full Checkpoint Data Size"

Comment: What is the job doing, what state does it have? Why do you expect the incremental checkpoints to be smaller? The checkpoints are already very small, so it's hard to reason about what might be happening without more information.

Comment: Job process some kafka events. State contains some rules. Each time job  receives a new Kafka Event ,it matches against the rules and rules are the part of state. As the checkpointing is incremental, according to the documentation, flink only checkpoint the delta from the previous checkpoint. So the checkpointed data ( delta from previous checkpoint)  should be  smaller be smaller than the full checkpoint data.

Answer (score 0):

With the RocksDB state backend, incremental checkpoints are implemented by taking advantage of how RocksDB works internally. What this means is that an incremental checkpoint is taken by only copying (to the distributed file system where the checkpoints are stored) new SST files that were created since the previous checkpoint.

Another aspect of this is that Flink checkpoints small chunks of state (by default, any chunk less than 20k bytes in size) in the root metadata file for the checkpoint, rather than in SST files. This behavior is controlled by [state.storage.fs.memory-threshold](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/config/#state-storage-fs-memory-threshold).

You have very little state, so it's all going into the metadata file. So in your case there's no practical difference between full checkpointing and incremental checkpointing.

If you were to reduce `state.storage.fs.memory-threshold` to 0, then you would see a change -- but probably for the worse. Then the incremental checkpoints might be larger than the full ones, because then Flink would be copying over the uncompacted SST files. If your state is changing from one checkpoint to another, the incremental checkpoints would include both the old and new state, up until RocksDB does a compaction. Incremental checkpoints are only helpful when you have a large amount of state.

For a deeper explaination, see [Improvements for large state and recovery in Flink](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tn_uk5EDiv8), which is a Flink Forward talk by Stefan Richter, who did the implementation.